# Note Board Web Part adding spaces in the middle of words

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, social-note

This is a typical OOTB SP2010. I have observed that comments entered into a Note Board Web Part will end up with spaces injected in the middle of words, at what appear to be random points.

Examle: I type in a couple of paragraphs into a comment, and it is gramatically and spelling correct. Upon saving the comment, though, it posts with spaces stuffed in between words at odd points.

If I copy-and-paste the resulting comment into a text editor, I find the spaces at (typical example)...
"You ca n view that" with the mystery space at char 161.
"statements t o set" with the mystery space at char 313.
And it continues on at about, but not exactly, the same spacing.

When I find a similarly broken-up comment, the spaces show up within 20 chars of one another, but they do end broken up about every 160 chars or so. And they are turly spaces, not just a line break.

Has anybody seen this behavior? Is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

this is known issue and you have to apply the hotfix to fix this.August Cu 2013 have this fix.

"When you post a line that contains more than 80 words on a note board on a SharePoint Server 2010 page, a white space is added to the line unexpectedly."

[Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817592/en-us)
[August CU 2103](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817570/en-us)